# Why are /dev/sdX not persistent and we have to use udev rules?

Tags: linux, udev, devices

Why are the /dev/sdX names not persistent and we have to use udev rules or something else? Why the name changes? Is it only the name and permissions or does something else change as well? Why?

Comment: Because no one bothered to implement persistent/reserved device names in kernel. It could be done other ways, but for kernel, assigning them in detection order (first come, first serve, with random results) is just that much simpler, and userspace can easily identify by content (UUID, LABEL, ...). And even if the kernel bothered to change this system, you'd kind of still have to use UUIDs anyway. Static device names won't help you if your partition numbers change, or if your volume groups are renamed, etc

Comment: Because it would be very complex. Do you want sda to be the first disk, but when you setup your computer, are you sure you put it in the right connector? What about adding a new hard disk? How do you know what you want to be the first? (and without knowing the disk, it can not read a configuration file to check it). Simple way (and Unix kernel ideas): let's a program to decide it (less hardcoded names and policies in kernels).